# iPod classic 1st gen - Transfer music to new computer

Tags: itunes, ipod-classic

I used to use an old desktop to load music into my iPod. I no longer have access to it, but I now have iTunes on my laptop.

How do I prevent all the music already on iPod from from being deleted when I load more music from my new laptop?

Comment: Are you using Windows or macOS on your laptop? How did you migrate your data from your Desktop PC to your laptop?

Comment: There are applications that allow you to get such data off your iPod, but you need to provide details on the computer you are using for us to help you.